# Primefaces inplace editor inside dynamically loaded p:accordionPanel reordering ArrayList on edit

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, arraylist

I'm using PrimeFaces 4.0 to to load a list of notes into a dynamic number of `p:accordionPanel` tabs inside a dialog. The dialog is opened when the user clicks on the row of a `p:datatable`. This list is of type `ArrayList< Note >`, with `Note` being the enitity bean for a `Notes` SQL table. The `Notes` table has a `@ManyToOne` relationship with a `Users` table.

Inside each `p:accordionPanel` tab, I am using `p:inplace`, `p:calendar` and `p:selectManyCheckbox` to set various parameters for each note.

I have no problem with the `p:calendar` and `p:selectManyCheckbox` code.

However when I edit a parameter using `p:inplace`, it appears to change the order of the `Note` objects contained within the `ArrayList`. 
So when I close and reopen the dialog, the edited note has moved to a new position in the `accordionPanel`.

I have confirmed that the objects within the `ArrayList` have been reordered by calling the `description` parameter of the first `Note` object in the `ArrayList`, using the code below from within the `p:accordionPanel`:

```
<h:outputText value="Description: " />
<h:outputText value="#{userDAO.notes.get(0).description}" />
```

The relevant code snippet from the JSF HTML page is:

```
<p:accordionPanel id="accordionPanelNotes"
    value="#{userDAO.visits}"
    var="accordionNotesList" multiple="true"
    activeIndex="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20">

    <p:tab title="#{accordionNotesList.dateTime}"
    id="tabTitleNotes">
        <h:outputText value="Description: *" />
        <h:outputText value="#{userDAO.notes.get(0).description}" />

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
        Description:
        <p:inplace emptyLabel="--empty--"
            id="ajaxInplaceNotesDescription" editor="true">
            <p:ajax event="save"
                listener="#{userDAO.handleEditSave}"
                update="accordionPanelNotes" oncomplete="updateNotesTable()"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{accordionNotesList.description}"
                required="true" label="text" />
        </p:inplace>

        ...

</p:accordionPanel>
```

The `userDAO.handleEditSave()` method:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void handleEditSave() throws SecurityException,
        IllegalStateException, RollbackException, HeuristicMixedException,
        HeuristicRollbackException, NamingException, NotSupportedException,
        SystemException {

    utx.begin();

        User user = (User) em.find(User.class, this.selectedUserRow.getId());

        user.setNotes(this.selectedUserRow.getNotes());

        em.merge(user);

    utx.commit();

}
```

The getter and setter for `Note`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();

public List<Note> getNotes() {
    return this.getNotes();
}

public void setNotes(List<Note> notes) {
    this.setNotes(notes);
}
```

The only thing I can think of that might be causing this behaviour is if the line `user.setNotes(this.selectedUserRow.getNotes())` from the `handleEditSave()` method is jumbling the order somehow.

What might be causing the order of the objects within the `ArrayList` to change?

Answer (score 0):

After firing `System.out.println()` methods at my code like a machine gun(!) I came to the conclusion that when a parameter in an entity bean inside a list is changed, the list will not necessarily be in the same order as it was before the change. Further googling came up with the solution of adding the annotation `@OrderBy` to the `List< Note >` declaration in the `User` model as follows:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy
private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
```

This will force the list to be filled with `Note` objects ordered by the primary key in the database.

In my case, i was simply luck that, on first load, the list had been filled in order of the rows of the database, which corresponds to that of the primary key order.

It's also possible to force the list to be ordered by a column other than the primary key by using the annotation `@OrderBy("nameOfAnotherColumn")`